# How to get Call log For Incoming and outgoing calls Programmatically

Tags: android

Call log not showing up to date list incoming and outgoing calls in listview in android above 6.0 version

Comment: Could you please show some code?

Comment: you are probably missing the permission for it, have you tried requesting for it with [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)